# R strsplit: Split based on character except when a specific character follows

Tags: regex, r, string, split

Say I have a vector of character strings like

```
split_these = c("File Location:C:\\Documents","File Location:Pete's Computer","File Location:")
```

I want to split each element in this vector based on ":" except for when a "\" follows it. What I want is for something that returns something like

```
#preferred solution
"File Location" "C:\\Documents"
"File Location" "Pete's Computer"
"File Location" ""
```

or

```
#less preferred but still great
"File Location" "C:\\Documents"
"File Location" "Pete's Computer"
"File Location"
```

I've tried the following

```
strsplit(split_these, ":")
[[1]]
[1] "File Location" "C"             "\\Documents"  

[[2]]
[1] "File Location" "Pete Computer"

[[3]]
[1] "File Location"

strsplit(split_these, ":[^\\]")
[[1]]
[1] "File Location" ":\\Documents" 

[[2]]
[1] "File Location" "ete Computer" 

[[3]]
[1] "File Location:"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using PCREs with a negative lookahead assertion. Also note that you need to double-escape the backslash because it serves as a metacharacter in both R strings and in regex syntax.

```
strsplit(perl=T,split_these,':(?!\\\\)');
## [[1]]
## [1] "File Location" "C:\\Documents"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "File Location"   "Pete's Computer"
##
## [[3]]
## [1] "File Location"
```

If you want to simplify the list into a single character vector:

```
do.call(c,strsplit(perl=T,split_these,':(?!\\\\)'));
## [1] "File Location" "C:\\Documents" "File Location" "Pete's Computer" "File Location"
```

---

I figured out a hack to get the trailing empty string field. Since `strsplit()` always omits a final empty field, we can simply concatenate the delimiter onto the end of every input string. If there was no trailing delimiter in the original string, then the new empty field will be omitted, not changing the result. If there *was* a trailing delimiter in the original string, then we'll get the empty field we want:

```
do.call(c,strsplit(perl=T,paste0(split_these,':'),':(?!\\\\)'));
## [1] "File Location" "C:\\Documents" "File Location" "Pete's Computer" "File Location" ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over elements of `split_these` with `read.dcf` gives a named character vector which could be reformed into a data.frame:

```
v <- drop(do.call("cbind", lapply(split_these, function(x) read.dcf(textConnection(x)))))
```

giving:

```
> v
    File Location     File Location     File Location 
  "C:\\Documents" "Pete's Computer"                ""
```

or

```
> stack(v)[2:1]
```

giving:

```
            ind          values
1 File Location   C:\\Documents
2 File Location Pete's Computer
3 File Location
```