# split character at deliminator conditionally negative lookahead assertion

Tags: r, regex, pcre

I want to split a string at `.` or `:` unless the next character is `)`

Following this question: [R strsplit: Split based on character except when a specific character follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213535/r-strsplit-split-based-on-character-except-when-a-specific-character-follows) why isn't

```
strsplit("Glenelg (Vic.)",'\\.|:(?!\\))', perl = TRUE)
```

returning

```
[[1]]
[1] "Glenelg (Vic)"
```

instead it splits at the `.`, like so:

```
[1] "Glenelg (Vic" ")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not grouped correctly. `\.|:(?!\))` matches a `.` anywhere in a string or a `:` not followed with `)`. If you group `.` and `:` patterns, `'(?:\\.|:)(?!\\))'`, it will work.

However, you may use a better regex version based on a character class:

```
strsplit("Glenelg (Vic.)",'[.:](?!\\))', perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "Glenelg (Vic.)"
```

Here, `[.:](?!\))` matches either `.` or `:` that are both not immediately followed with `)`.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/I56ofK/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_split("Glenelg (Vic.)","[\\.:](?!\\))")
[[1]]
[1] "Glenelg (Vic.)"
```